# Passing a collection of partially editable objects to an algorithm

Tags: c++, arguments, constants, abstract-class

I simplified my problem with a simple example : immagine I manage a collection of elements `std::vector<Element>`, each element having several members :

```
struct Element
{
  public:
    double foo;
    double bar;
};
```

Then, I want to define an abstract class `BarEvaluator`, for algorithms computing the values of `b` from the values of `a`. My first idea is the following :

```
class BarEvaluator
{
  public:
    virtual void evaluate(std::vector<Element>& elements) const = 0;
};
```

From that, I can implement several algorithms, for example, an algorithme computing the `bar` values as the square of the `foo` values :

```
class SqrBarEvaluator
{
  public:
    virtual void evaluate(std::vector<Element>& elements) const
    {
      for(unsigned long int i = 0; i < elements.size(); ++i)
        elements[i].bar = elements[i].foo * elements[i].foo;
    }
};
```

This is working well. But I think it's not a really good architecture, because **my algorithm is also able to modify the `foo` values**. I don't want that.

Then I would like to be able to give my collection to the algorithm with a kind of "filter" allowing to modify only the `bar` variable and not the `foo` variable in each element. Is it possible with C++98 ? I have no idea how to do that.

**Remark 1 :** I don't want to do that with `public` or `private` in `Element`. You can immagine I also want to create algorithms `FooEvaluator` computing `foo` values from `bar` values, with writing access to `foo` and not to `bar`.

**Remark 2 :** The algorithm can require all the collection to compute each value.

Comment: Isn´t that exactly the reason why protected, private, and the concept of getter/setter method exist?

Comment: No, I don't want to restrict the access to `Element` for everyone, juste for the algorithm.

Comment: why are you using C++98?

Comment: In the general case, as you describe it,  `// DO NOT MODIFY .foo OR A CADUCHON WILL COME AFTER YOU` seems the best solution indeed. C++ would offer various solutions involving another layer of abstraction, but I'd avise against using them in this case.

Comment: :-) Of course, documentation can also be a solution. I though about a proxy over the collection, but it seems ugly and very complex to implement.

Comment: Create an abstraction for the whole looping process. Check for ideas @ <algorithm>  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm

Comment: As for the immutability, you can create a wrapper object, but then accessing the individual elements of the struct has to be function calls. As @peterchen said, the usual approach in C++ is to warn the developer (document it!) - there are myriad of examples in the standard library (e.g.: satisfy these contrainsts, or else... UB)

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: because my code has to compile under gcc 4.1.2 (Red Hat 5.7 default compiler)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should pull the loop out of the interface.

```
class BarEvaluator
{
  public:
    virtual double evaluate(const Element& element) const = 0;
};

class SqrBarEvaluator
{
  public:
    virtual double evaluate(const Element& element) const
    {
      return element.foo * element.foo;
    }
};
```

Then you call it like this:

```
std::vector<Element> elements;
...
for (std::vector<Element>::iterator it = elements.begin(); it != elements.end(); ++it) {
    it->bar = barEvaluator.evaluate(*it);
}
```

Comment: Actually, the algorithm can require all the collection to compute the value of `bar`. Example : an algorithm computing the distance to the mean of the other values. It's the case in my real problem.

Comment: @Caduchon: That's a two step process. 1) iterate an calculate the mean. 2) iterate and calculate the distances. Both can be solved with algorithms.

Comment: In this case, the algorithmic class can't be const.

Comment: you mean the instance? why is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrapper:

```
class BarElementWrapper
{
public:
    BarElementWrapper(Element& e) : elem(e) { }
    double getFoo() { return elem.foo; }
    void setBar(double b) { elem.bar = b; }

private:
    Element& elem;
}
```

And then your algorithm receives a collection of BarElementWrapper.